# Integral paradox: Deterministic integral interpreted as limiting case of stochastic integral

Tags: calculus, stochastic-integrals

The value of a [stochastic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_calculus), in this case integrating a [Wiener process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) with respect to itself $$\int_0^T W(t)\;dW(t)$$ is dependent on the chosen position of the endpoint of the subintervals.

For example the [Ito integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ito_calculus) (leftpoint chosen) gives: $$\int_0^T W(t)\;dW(t)=\frac{W(T)^2}{2}-\frac{T}{2}$$
The extra term $-T/2$ is the so called Ito correction term.

My question concerns this very term: If $W(t)$ wasn't stochastic but deterministic the classical calculus would be used and this extra term wouldn't be there. You can e.g. show via simulation that it disappears when you set $\sigma=0$ and thereby render Brownian motion deterministic.

**My question**
When the deterministic integral is interpreted as the limiting case ($\sigma \rightarrow 0$) of the stochastic integral where the extra term $-T/2$ vanishes when $\sigma$ reaches $0$ (and thereby becomes deterministic), how can it be that the extra term $-T/2$ is only dependent on $T$ and not on $\sigma$?

Comment: The variance of $W(T)$ is $\sigma T$.

Comment: @Michael: Could you please elaborate on that and put it into an answer. That would be great - thank you!

Comment: TYPO: It's $\sigma^2 T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B(t)$ be the standard Wiener process, so that $\operatorname{var}(B(t))=t$.  Let $W(t) = \sigma B(t)$, so that $\operatorname{var}(W(t))=\sigma^2 t$.  If
$$
\int_0^T B(t)\;dB(t) = \frac{B(T)^2}{2} - \frac T2,
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^T W(t) \; dW(t) & = \sigma^2\int_0^T B(t)\;dB(t) \\  \\
& = \sigma^2\left( \frac{B(T)^2}{2} - \frac T2 \right) = \frac{\sigma^2 B(T)^2}{2} - \frac{\sigma^2 T}{2} \\  \\
&  = \frac{W(T)^2}{2} - \frac{\sigma^2 T}{2}.
\end{align}
$$
Now let $\sigma^2\to0$.

Comment: Thank you, the result squares very well with my simulations!